# Правильное оформление CSS цветов через кастомайзер темы Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Добавил в кастомайзер темы Wordpress поле для выбора цвета body сайта. Само собой, оригинал цвета прописал в style.css, а цвет пользователя как бы перезаписывает его в коде шаблона, вот так:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('setting-body-color', '#fafafa'); ?>">
```

Нормально ли использовать такой код или нет? Есть ли альтернативы?

Comment: Ну а почему нет. Примерно так темы и делают.

Comment: еще как вариант можно создать php файл который будет генерировать стили из настроек и подключать его инлайн используя wp_add_inline_style